# Making constant global variables of a custom struct type

Tags: go, types, constants

I want to create a "class" to handle the input validation. I first make a type of `Input` which is a string for storing user input and a type of `REGP` which store the regex pattern and the description of the pattern. I created two constant instances `REGP_LOGINNAME` and `REGP_PASSWORD`. But I get error of `const initializer REGP literal is not a constant`. Why?

```
package aut

import "regexp"

type Input string

type REGP struct {
    pattern string
    Descr   string
}

const REGP_LOGINNAME = REGP{ //const initializer REGP literal is not a constant
    "regex pattern 1",
    "regex description 1",
}

const REGP_PASSWORD = REGP{ //const initializer REGP literal is not a constant
    "regex pattern 2",
    "regex description 2",
}

func (i Input) isMatch(regp REGP) bool {
    isMatchREGP, _ := regexp.MatchString(regp.pattern, string(i))
    return isMatchREGP
}
```

Error Message:

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -i [/home/casper/gopath/codespace_v2.6.6/dev/server_side/golang/go_codespace_v2.1/server/lib/aut]
# _/home/casper/gopath/codespace_v2.6.6/dev/server_side/golang/go_codespace_v2.1/server/lib/aut
./validation.go:15: const initializer REGP literal is not a constant
./validation.go:20: const initializer REGP literal is not a constant
Error: process exited with code 2.
```

Comment: There are boolean constants, rune constants, integer constants, floating-point constants, complex constants, and string constants. REGP isn't one of those.

Comment: @JimB - You mean that I cannot make a custom type constant? Do you have any idea to make it looks better?

Comment: Correct https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants. Most code would use a variable, or just make the regex string const

Comment: Is there a way to wrap `pattern` and `Descr` together to form global variables?

Comment: Yes, you can create a global variable of type REGP.

Comment: Could you give me some hints? I get error on my every try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118095/discussion-between-casper-li-and-jimb).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consants in Go can only be scalar values (eg. `2`, `true`, `3.14`, `"and more"`) or any expression that is composed of only constants (eg. `1 + 2`, `"hello " + "world"`, or `2 * math.Pi * 1i`).

This means that struct types such as your `REGP_LOGINNAME` which are not scalar values cannot be assigned to constants. Instead, use a variable:

```
var (
    REGP_LOGINNAME = REGP{
        pattern: `/^(?=^.{6,20}$)^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[._-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/`,
        Descr:   "regex description 1",
    }
    REGP_PASSWORD = REGP{
        pattern: `/^(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()]*$/`,
        Descr:   "regex description 2",
    }
)
```

### Further Reading

- https://blog.golang.org/constants

*Aside:* I don't know your use case, of course, but I really **really** doubt you actually need or want to use a regexp to validate a users password. Instead, consider passing it through the [OpaqueString profile of PRECIS](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/secure/precis#Profile) (a framework for handling and enforcing safety of unicode strings; the opaque string profile was designed to handle passwords). Similarly, the UsernameCaseMapped and UsernameCasePreserved profiles (also implemented in the linked package) can be used for usernames to ensure you don't end up with two usernames that look the same but have different unicode characters in them. Further validation can also be done, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I finally find that it seems not possible to make the `REGP` pointer or its variable inside to be constant. So I just make them global variables.

```
package aut

import "regexp"

type Input string

type REGP struct {
    pattern string
    Descr   string
}

var REGP_LOGINNAME = REGP{
    pattern: "/^(?=^.{6,20}$)^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[._-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/",
    Descr:   "regex description 1",
}

var REGP_PASSWORD = REGP{
    pattern: "/^(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()]*$/",
    Descr:   "regex description 2",
}

func (i Input) isMatch(regp REGP) bool {
    isMatchREGP, _ := regexp.MatchString(regp.pattern, string(i))
    return isMatchREGP
}
```